# The counting GF of admissible combinatorial classes are analytic at $0$

Tags: reference-request, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

I found a presentation on the internet about analytic combinatorics, in said presentation the following is mentioned

[image]

I don't remember seeing the proof of this statement in Flajolet's book, so a reference where I can see a good proof of this statement would help.